# How do you install language support?

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, language-support, special-characters

How to produce diacritical (accented) characters under Ubuntu 14.04? I used to be able to do it under 12.04 by installing the relevant language support, however under Ubuntu 14.04 the only available language seems to be English. The language support seems to relate to the language of the interface rather than the keyboard input. When I upgraded from ubuntu 12.04 to 14.04 on my previous computer, the language support seemed to be unaffected. How come I cannot have it on my current one which had the 14.04 installed from scratch? If there's no way of getting this feature, could you please let me know how do downgrade to the 12.04 version? Maybe upon upgrading it, I could keep my language settings?

Answer (score 1):

The panel for setting keyboard layout is named *Text Entry* in 14.04.